# Populate combo box with Document/View separation (MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC SDI application with a series of views that I can switch at runtime based on the type of list item that is selected in another view. Because they are dynamically created, they require an empty constructor, so I can't pass in initial values to populate the view's fields with the data from the selected item. I thought about using SendMessage to send a message to the view with either wParam or lParam being a pointer to the selected item, but that doesn't seem like very good Document/View separation because my view now has to know about the members of my document object. Am I being too picky? If not, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the `SendMessage` could just pass a `<type-of-list>` to the `View` and the view could call a function in the document which returns the fields required by the view, like

```
// define structure/class VIEWFIELDS which contain the items required by the View
VIEWFIELDS ViewFields;
nNextItem = 0;
nNextItem = pDoc->GetNextItem(nListType, nNextItem, &ViewFields);
```

until the function returns -1?

Comment: I like this idea much better than my first one. The only problem is that my data structures are complex, so sometimes I need to access members of a list inside the selected item, and use it to fill a dialog box. So I need to be able to iterate over `selectedItem->listOfStuff` I'm not sure how to do that without either the view having a pointer to `listOfStuff` or my document having a pointer to the `CComboBox` in the view... Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe I could have different function in the document for each type of object, each expecting a different type of structure? So I would have
`SIGNALVIEWFIELDS ViewFields;`
`nNextItem = 0;`
`nNextItem = pDoc->GetNextSignalItem(nListType, nNextItem, &ViewFields);`
That way I could put whatever type-specific lists I needed in the structure and the document could fill them as needed. It's not total separation, but it's not direct access either. What do you think?

Comment: If the view just needs to fill a combo box, the document could just return a string value -- but, to make things more generalised, your second comment would be better since you would easily be able to add more fields and let each view use what ever fields it needs

Comment: I don't think it could just return a string if I need to fill a combo box with a variable number of strings; I need to call `CComboBox::AddString` on `x` number of strings, with x changing depending on the size of the selected item's member lists. But regardless, thanks for your help! Your answer will work with minor tweaks.